# Notification via @(user name) not working

Tags: support, comment, comment-replies

After changing my user name to D B Lim, it seems whenever someone does @D or 
@D B Lim, I don't get a notification. Is this some kind of glitch? Should I change my username to one that is just one word?

Thanks.

Comment: To help with the diagnostics: did Srivatsan's comment [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61521) reach you or not? Note that `@D` definitely doesn't work, as three characters from the username are at least required.

Comment: @J.M. No it did not work.

Comment: @DB: There's an exception if there are spaces in your user name. I just tested that one can notify you with `@DB`, although this has only 2 characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces to get the notification working if the first part of your username is only one letter, so `@dbl` or `@dblim` should work.

See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for much more details about the comment notifications.

Comment: Personally, I find it quite confusing when I find names that had spaces or dots in between. This post seems very useful. Thanks!

Comment: It is interesting to note that `@DB` (or `@db`) also works.

Comment: @Srivatsan: You may want to have a look at [this userscript](http://stackapps.com/questions/2138/) or [that one](http://stackapps.com/questions/2051/)

Comment: @Theo Wow, that should be really useful. Thanks! (A separate thanks for pointing me to stackapps. I hadn't known about this...)

Comment: @Hen Do those two-char names work per doc or per actual confirmed use?

Comment: @Bill: Well, you know what "documentation" means here - most of it is written by the community itself, after actual confirmed use. However, in this case it's documented [in an answer by a developer, namely balpha](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61960/allow-for-comment-reply-to-usernames-with-less-than-three-characters-in-first-wor/75809#75809). (That `@DB` will work is not _really_ documented there; this I tested myself.)

Answer (score 1):

Click the "help" link underneath the Add Comment button:

> The post author will always be notified of your comment. **To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work.** [Learn more…](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

The implication is that the user's name is "Peter Smith" so the lack of space is indicated there.

Additionally the Learn More link to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting is HIGHLY recommended.

Comment: I find it quite strange that the software does not somehow warn you when you type in an invalid at-name. Can't you simply highlight invalid at-names somehow? i.e. names which will not be pinged. I suppose my prior suggestion was too much work (i.e. also highlighting valid at-names and their targeted comment in matching colors - to achieve WYSIWYG adressing).

Comment: @BillDubuque Your post here has not given me any notifications. Aren't I supposed to get one?

Comment: @DBL Iirc only the author of the parent of the comment thread is defaultly notified (here Jeff). I don't know if it works to ping the questioner in a comment thread they are not in. Jeff? But I think this DBL ping should work. Did it?

Comment: @BillDubuque How come (at)DBL gives me a notification?

Comment: @DBL See Fabian's answer.

Comment: @DB, I can confirm what Bill wrote: if no `@` syntax is used, then you'll only be notified of comments to _your posts_, and this is _Jeff's post_. Thus, I used `@DB` to notify you of this comment, and it only works because you already participated in the comments here. Bill in his first comment had no way of notifying you.