# Tagging more than one person in a comment

Tags: feature-request, comment-replies

I have noticed then when I first wish to tag someone in a comment with "@" upon typing say "g" choices come up like "gauss" or "galois" depending on which user is mentioned in the thread. However when I want to do a second tag not only do such choices not show up but a yellow box shows up saying

"Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified."

What is the reason for this? Thanks.

Comment: This is [status-declined] on meta.stackoverflow.com: [Allow more than one @name notification per comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45273/152819).

Comment: can you also tag someone you know after posting a new question that has not been answered yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See Fabian's answer to [your previous question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2915) for how @-notifications work.

To partially address Bill Dubuque's comment on Jeff's [answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2922/1543), and to make double clear to you that the second @ will not send a notification, Stack implemented a smart system to show you who you can notify and to tell you that [you just can't notify more than one person per comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45273). This way you don't get disappointed when

1. You spelled the user's name wrong, hence the user doesn't get the notification.
2. You added a second @, and that user doesn't get the notification.

To repeat: a second @ notification has **never** been supported. Previously it just fails silently. Now at least it tells you that "hey buddy, that ain't gonna work."

Comment: It makes me wonder which was harder to code: implementing multiple notifications or that (annoying) popup message. :)

Comment: @cardinal I believe that restriction is 100% intentional, to limit users annoying too many people at once by notifying them in their global inboxes.

Comment: @WillieWong So that would mean if I want to notify two people I have to post two comments. Thanks.